# Django sending back parameters to the view

Tags: python, django, templates

I have trouble with one of the page of my project.

I have a page, use to look up mouvements history :
The Page url contain an ID to search for a specific location for the query
Once on the page, the user must choose a begin and end date and then with those informations a sql query get the informations in my view and django fill a datatable with the result.

My problem is how do i send back the dates informations to the view once the user picked them on the template ?

Edit:

This is my view :

```
def historique(request, pk):
    silo = pk[:2]
    cellule = pk[-2:]
    full = pk
    """ Connection to server [SRV-APPLIC1\SQL_SUPV] - Database [BD_SITE] """
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=SRV-APPLIC1\SQL_SUPV;"
                      "Database=BD_SITE;"
                      "UID=xx;"
                      "PWD=xxxxxxxx;")
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    """MS SQL CALL TO STORED PROCEDURE SP_webGET_PBASCULE """
    arguments = (full, 'RCP', '01/01/2017','01/12/2017')
    cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_HISTO_CELLULE(?,?,?,?)}", arguments)
    mouvementRCPs = cursor.fetchall()
    arguments = (full, 'PT0', '01/01/2017','01/12/2017')
    cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_HISTO_CELLULE(?,?,?,?)}", arguments)
    mouvementPT0s = cursor.fetchall()
    arguments = (full, 'PT0', '01/01/2017','01/12/2017')
    cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_HISTO_CELLULE(?,?,?,?)}", arguments)
    mouvementCHGs = cursor.fetchall()
    return render(request, 'PageHistos.html', locals())
```

Template :

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contrôle commande niveau cellule</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 12 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="{% static 'css/Gestion_Mouvements.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/PageHistos.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/base/jquery-ui.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"  media="all">
<link href="{% static 'css//bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js' %}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var jQTHistoOptions =
   {
      show: false,
      event: 'click',
      collapsible: false
   };
   $("#jQTHisto").tabs(jQTHistoOptions);
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#entrantTab').dataTable( {
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "scrollX": true,
  "lengthMenu": [ [-1], ["All"] ]
} );
 $('#ptsTab').dataTable( {
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "scrollX": true,
  "lengthMenu": [ [-1], ["All"] ]
} );
 $('#sortantTab').dataTable( {
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "scrollX": true,
  "lengthMenu": [ [-1], ["All"] ]
} );
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="" id="Label2" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:11px;width:1245px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:21;">Contrôle commande niveau cellule</label>
<label for="" id="Label5" style="position:absolute;left:405px;top:50px;width:116px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:22;">Silo :</label>
<label for="" id="Label1" style="position:absolute;left:685px;top:50px;width:116px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:23;">Cellule :</label>
<div id="jQTHisto" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:125px;width:1243px;height:507px;z-index:24;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#jqthisto-page-0"><span>Historique des mouvements entrants</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#jqthisto-page-1"><span>Historique des points 0</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#jqthisto-page-2"><span>Historique des mouvements sortants</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div style="height:485px;" id="jqthisto-page-0">
<label for="" id="Label4" style="position:absolute;left:288px;top:63px;width:116px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:0;">Cellule :</label>
<input type="text" id="Editbox3" style="position:absolute;left:359px;top:61px;width:60px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:1;" name="Editbox1" value="{{full}}" spellcheck="false" class="span3 datatab">
<label for="" id="Label6" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:63px;width:116px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:2;">Espèce :</label>
<input type="text" id="Editbox4" style="position:absolute;left:523px;top:61px;width:60px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:3;" name="Editbox1" value="{{cellule}}" spellcheck="false" class="span3 datatab">
<label for="" id="Label7" style="position:absolute;left:617px;top:63px;width:116px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:4;">Produit :</label>
<input type="text" id="Editbox5" style="position:absolute;left:689px;top:61px;width:60px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:5;" name="Editbox1" value="{{cellule}}" spellcheck="false" class="span3 datatab">
<div id="Html6" style="position:absolute;left:12px;top:101px;width:1222px;height:400px;z-index:6">
<table id="entrantTab" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date et heure création</th>
                <th>Récolte</th>
                <th>Mouvement</th>
                <th>Sous domaine</th>
                <th>Produit</th>
                <th>Poids</th>
                <th>Livreur</th>
                <th>Immatriculation</th>
                <th>Code Caract 1</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 1</th>
                <th>Code Caract 2</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 2</th>
                <th>Code Caract 3</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 3</th>
                <th>Code Caract 4</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 4</th>
                <th>Code Caract 5</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 5</th>
                <th>Code Caract 6</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 6</th>
                <th>Code Caract 7</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 7</th>
                <th>Code Caract 8</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 8</th>
                <th>Code Caract 9</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 9</th>
                <th>Code Caract 10</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 10</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
           {% for mouvement in mouvementRCPs %}
                <th>{{mouvement.Datetime2}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Recolte}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Type_Mouvement}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Sous_Domaine}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Produit}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Poids}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Livreur}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Immat}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.CodeCaract1}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract1}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Carac}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract2}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract3}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract3}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract4}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract4}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract5}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract5}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract6}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract6}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract7}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract7}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract8}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract8}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.CodeCaract9}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract9}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract10}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract10}}</th>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table></div>
</div>
<div style="height:485px;" id="jqthisto-page-1">
<div id="htmlDateTimePicker3" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:60px;width:250px;height:30px;z-index:0">
<div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-01-01T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - hh:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input1" >
     <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value='{{listPB.2}}' readonly>
     <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        minuteStep: 1,
    });
</script>
<div id="htmlDateTimePicker4" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:100px;width:250px;height:30px;z-index:0">
<div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-01-01T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - hh:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input1" >
     <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value='{{listPB.2}}' readonly>
     <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        minuteStep: 1,
    });
</script>

<label for="" id="Label3" style="position:absolute;left:288px;top:63px;width:116px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:9;">Cellule :</label>
<input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:359px;top:61px;width:60px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:10;" name="Editbox1" value="{{cellule}}" spellcheck="false" class="span3 datatab">
<div id="Html7" style="position:absolute;left:272px;top:101px;width:962px;height:400px;z-index:11">
<table id="ptsTab" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date et heure création</th>
                <th>Type deMouvement</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
           {% for mouvement in mouvementPT0s %}
                <th>{{mouvement.Datetime2}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Type_Mouvement}}</th>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table></div>
</div>
<div style="height:485px;" id="jqthisto-page-2">
<div id="htmlDateTimePicker5" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:60px;width:250px;height:30px;z-index:0">
<div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-01-01T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - hh:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input1" >
     <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value='{{listPB.2}}' readonly>
     <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        minuteStep: 1,
    });
</script>
<div id="htmlDateTimePicker6" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:100px;width:250px;height:30px;z-index:0">
<div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-01-01T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - hh:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input1" >
     <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value='{{listPB.2}}' readonly>
     <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        minuteStep: 1,
    });
</script>

<label for="" id="Label8" style="position:absolute;left:288px;top:62px;width:116px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:14;">Cellule :</label>
<input type="text" id="Editbox6" style="position:absolute;left:359px;top:60px;width:60px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:15;" name="Editbox1" value="{{cellule}}" spellcheck="false" class="span3 datatab">
<label for="" id="Label9" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:62px;width:116px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:16;">Espèce :</label>
<label for="" id="Label10" style="position:absolute;left:617px;top:62px;width:116px;height:19px;line-height:19px;z-index:17;">Produit :</label>
<input type="text" id="Editbox7" style="position:absolute;left:523px;top:60px;width:60px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:18;" name="Editbox1" value="{{cellule}}" spellcheck="false" class="span3 datatab">
<input type="text" id="Editbox8" style="position:absolute;left:689px;top:60px;width:60px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:19;" name="Editbox1" value="{{cellule}}" spellcheck="false" class="span3 datatab">
<div id="Html8" style="position:absolute;left:275px;top:100px;width:962px;height:400px;z-index:20">
<table id="sortantTab" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date et heure création</th>
                <th>Récolte</th>
                <th>Mouvement</th>
                <th>Sous domaine</th>
                <th>Produit</th>
                <th>Poids</th>
                <th>Livreur</th>
                <th>Immatriculation</th>
                <th>Code Caract 1</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 1</th>
                <th>Code Caract 2</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 2</th>
                <th>Code Caract 3</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 3</th>
                <th>Code Caract 4</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 4</th>
                <th>Code Caract 5</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 5</th>
                <th>Code Caract 6</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 6</th>
                <th>Code Caract 7</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 7</th>
                <th>Code Caract 8</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 8</th>
                <th>Code Caract 9</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 9</th>
                <th>Code Caract 10</th>
                <th>Valeur Caract 10</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
           {% for mouvement in mouvementCHGs %}
                <th>{{mouvement.Datetime2}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Recolte}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Type_Mouvement}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Sous_Domaine}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Produit}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Poids}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Livreur}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Immat}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.CodeCaract1}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract1}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Carac}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract2}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract3}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract3}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract4}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract4}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract5}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract5}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract6}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract6}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract7}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract7}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract8}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract8}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.CodeCaract9}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract9}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Code_Caract10}}</th>
                <th>{{mouvement.Val_Caract10}}</th>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="htmlDateTimePicker1" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:60px;width:250px;height:30px;z-index:0">
<div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-01-01T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - hh:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input1" >
     <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value='{{listPB.2}}' readonly>
     <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        minuteStep: 1,
    });
</script>
<div id="htmlDateTimePicker2" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:100px;width:250px;height:30px;z-index:0">
<div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-01-01T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - hh:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input1" >
     <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value='{{listPB.2}}' readonly>
     <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        minuteStep: 1,
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="ebVehicule" style="position:absolute;left:459px;top:48px;width:60px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:27;" name="Editbox1" value="{{silo}}" spellcheck="false" class="span3 datatab">
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:767px;top:48px;width:69px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:28;" name="Editbox1" value="{{cellule}}" spellcheck="false" class="span3 datatab">
</body>
</html>
```

Since i wasn't able to do it at the moment the procedure are called with fixed date.
What i want to do is the user comes on the page, choose two dates, hit research button and that calls back the view to call the procedure with the right parameters and then fill the datatables with the results

Comment: you can send dates through `URL` using Regular expression

Comment: please put some of your code. If u want to get some data but don't reload page you can use javascript if i understood your question.

Comment: To send information from a web page to the backend you usually use a form.

Comment: Are you sure it is wise to post the database password here `cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=SRV-APPLIC1\SQL_SUPV;"
                      "Database=BD_SITE;"
                      "UID=xxxx;"
                      "PWD=xxxxxx;")` (original content x'ed)

Comment: it's just a temporary db for the tests but yeah still not wise thanks